# How to convert text to speech for OSX in Swift playground

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm trying to learn how to do text to speech for OSX (**not** iOS) in Swift. I have a playground with code:

```
import Cocoa

let synth = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
synth.startSpeaking( "Hello World" )
```

Which seems to run, but no sound occurs. In Xcode, there is a little blue triangle in the lower left corner, which I press thinking it might do something, but sadly no:

[image: Picture of Xcode interface with blue triangle in lower left corner]

Any ideas how to convert text to speech for OSX in a Swift playground? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSSpeechSynthesizer`'s `.startSpeaking` needs to execute in a background task, but by default this is not possible in a Playground.

You can enable it by importing `PlaygroundSupport` and setting asynchronous mode, like this:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```